# FullResultSet error during migration with mssql (sql server)

Tags: python, sql-server, django, migration

I am trying to connect a SQL Server database with Django.
But when I do "migration", I have this error :

```
File "...\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\where.py", line 174, in as_sql
    raise FullResultSet
django.core.exceptions.FullResultSet
```

My tables are created in database but when I want to do another migration or make migration, I have this error.

I am using pyodbc and mssql-django packages

settings.py :

```
DATABASES = {
    'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
    'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
    'CONN_HEALTH_CHECKS': False,
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': '***',
    'USER': '***',
    'PASSWORD': '***',
    'HOST': '***',
    'PORT': '***',
    'OPTIONS': {
         'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
         "setdecoding": [
             {"sqltype": pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, "encoding": 'utf-8'},
             {"sqltype": pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, "encoding": 'utf-8'}],
         "setencoding": [
             {"encoding": "utf-8"}],
         },
    'TIME_ZONE': None,
}
```

When I drop django.migrations table in the database, I no longer have the error for 'makemigration' but there is the "table already exists" error. This recreates the 'django.migrations' table and the error appears again.